# Use *ngIf with Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Good morning.
I'm developing an application in which I have clients and invoices on the same array (of objects).
The thing is that I'm displaying them all and there's a boolean property named `client` which indicates if this object is client or invoice (true-false).

I'm doing a for to show them and what I want to do is to show the clients in another way than the invoices.

I've tried this and it's working well:

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
  {{ item.client? "Client" : item.text}}
</button>
```

But as I said, what I want to do is to change the clients colour and I can't do it if they're not inside some tag. The trouble that I'm having is to make an if-else to display a tag if it's client and display another if it's not.

I've also tried with:

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
  <p *ngIf="item.client == false">{{item.text}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="item.client == true">{{item.text}}</p>
</button>
```

But again, as the other things it didn't work.
Would be great to find a solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular way, you can use **ngClass** for better rendering.

ex: **[ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}"**

Depending on the condition it will call the class in css.

you can try this to solve the problem.

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
  <p [ngClass]="{'first': item.client=='Client', 'second': item.text=='data'}">{{item.client ? 'Client' : item.text}}</p>
</button>
```

Any queries in ngClass please check this link https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

I hope this it will work

Comment: Cool, this one is interesting. As you can see in one answer behind I was discussing why the <p> wrapping doesn't work when I bind the content but in your case, it's working well. Thank you, there they go your first points of good response ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
 <p *ngIf="item.client">Client</p>
 <p *ngIf="!item.client">{{item.text}}</p>
```

Comment: I was trying this right now, the thing is that it works if you put it inside <ion-label> or <ion-item> but not if it's inside <p> or <button>, it's weird.. :/

Comment: well that's strange, can you produce a stackblitz

Comment: Of course, see, I did it on the "home" page. It's a simple display of items. In one I'm using the ion labels and the button and p in the other (which is not showing), it's more to research than the problem itself by now, haha https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zvh4cr

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```html
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)"
    [class.bg-client]="item.client" 
    [class.bg-invoice]="!item.client" >
  {{item.client ? 'Client' : item.text}}
</button>
```

The **bg-client** and **bg-invoice** can be replaced with your classes.

Comment: It's not working for now but I've got the idea. I didn't know that you can put this as [class] = "condition", is it a known practice?

Comment: you can do that way or [ngClass]="{'bg-client': item.client, 'bg-invoice': !item.client}"